# Return mixed results from parent and child table with condition on child table (MSSQL)

Tags: sql-server

The parent table is storing the latest update time for machine2 and machine3, but the updates themselves are stored in the child table, and I would like to return the latest update time for each machine that is a check (latest "check" record of the machine in the child table by time).

I can join the two, but I don't know how to state the condition, because I want to return other data which is in the parent table (e.g. tester)

**Parent table**

| id (PK) | time | title | tester |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 23:50 | machine2 | tester X |
| 3 | 18:40 | machine3 | tester Y |

**Child table**

| id | time | notes | Parent_entry (FK) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23:50 | test | 2 |
| 2 | 20:50 | check | 2 |
| 3 | 19:20 | check | 2 |
| 4 | 18:40 | test | 3 |
| 5 | 14:30 | check | 3 |

**Result needed**

| time | title | tester |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20:50 | machine2 | tester X |
| 14:30 | machine3 | tester Y |

Comment: Which column would you use to determine the latest, the `id` column or `time` column of the child table?

Comment: The time column in the child table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a **window function** such as [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) inside of a CTE to generate a unique integer series partitioned by each `Parent_entry` and ordered by the `time` descending and then use that dataset to filter out the latest records where the `notes = 'check'` like so:

```
WITH CTE_ChildTable_CheckOnly_Sorted AS
(
    SELECT 
        [time], 
        Parent_entry, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Parent_entry ORDER BY [time] DESC) AS SortId
    FROM ChildTable
    WHERE notes = 'check' -- Only "check" rows
)

SELECT S.[time], PT.title, PT.tester
FROM CTE_ChildTable_CheckOnly_Sorted AS S
INNER JOIN ParentTable AS PT
    ON S.Parent_entry = PT.Parent_entry
WHERE S.SortId = 1 -- Filters out only the latest rows by time
```

Note if your ParentTable has rows that don't exist in the ChildTable, and you want to keep those rows in the final results, then you need to use an outer join instead of an inner, and will need to do an `ISNULL()` on `S.[time]` and replace with `PT.[time]`. If all ParentTable rows have at least one correlating ChildTable row, then the above example is fine.